# Can this 500 watt Power Supply handle gtx 750 ti or gtx 760?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a simple office comp....i just want to install a gpu that i can improve gaming experience.

My computer spec:

Cpu: intel i3 4170 3.7 ghz

Ram : 2*4 ddr3

1TB Hdd

Motherboard: asRock 91m-s1-plus

Power supply pic: https://ibb.co/48GY7pw

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but 500w is the minimum for the 760....see minimum recommended system power....https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-760/specifications

Comment: Instead of the link to an image, think to write some specs of the PS you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this brand (from their home page they seem more like a distributor than a manufacturer), but I remember a PSU (from a brand I've removed from my mind) that was labelled "350W", but was unable to power a mini-ITX board with a Celeron. More, if the PSU is loaded near 100%, its efficiency drops (more heat, more AC power and risk of unattended power-off).

There are several power supply calculators online ([like this](https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator)) where you can test your configuration. I've tried your configurations, and in both cases 500W will be ok, but for the Gtx 760 the minimum power calculated is 435W (other PSU calculators gave me a minimum of 385W), that means a load more than 80%, and that PSU has no label "80 plus" or better, so you are entering in a dangerous zone.

So, my suggestion is to use a GTX 750 because the 760 has a power requirement that is too near the PSU limit, or buy a PSU from a well known PSU manufacturer (e.g. a PSU 500W 80 Plus Gold).